# spring boot controller with @Validated for @RequestParam List<String> not giving meaningful error message as defined

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I am facing some error message as defined below:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@Validated
@RequestMapping("api")
public class AdminController {

@Autowired
private TeacherService teacherService;

@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@Operation(summary = "Get list of students common to a given ist of teachers")
@GetMapping("commonstudents")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public CommonStudents listOfStudentsCommonToAGivenListOfTeachers(
        @Parameter(description = "list of teacher's email", example = "[\"teacher1@xyz.com\", \"teacher2@xyz.com\"]")
        @RequestParam(value = "teacher", required = false)
        @NotEmpty(message = "Please input at least one email") 
        List<@NotBlank(message = "teacher Email cannot be blank")
        @Email(message = "teacher email address must be in proper format") String> teacherEmails) {
    log.info("in AdminController::listOfStudentsCommonToAGivenListOfTeachers");
    log.info("listOfStudentsCommonToAGivenListOfTeachers: {}", teacherEmails);

    return teacherService.listOfStudentsCommonToAGivenListOfTeachers(teacherEmails);
    }
}
```

my controllerAdvice:

```
 @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ExceptionHandler({ConstraintViolationException.class})
    @ResponseBody
    public AdminResponse handleConstraintViolationException(HttpServletRequest req, ConstraintViolationException e) {

        List<String> errorMessages = e.getConstraintViolations().stream().map(violation -> violation.getPropertyPath().toString() + ": " + violation.getMessage()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        log.error("requestUrl : {}, occurred an error : {}, exception detail : {}", req.getRequestURI(), errorMessages, e);
        String collect = String.join(", ", errorMessages);
        return AdminResponse.failureResponse(collect);
    }
```

my endpoint1 on postman:

```
GET: http://localhost:8081/api/commonstudents?teacher=1&teacher=teacher2@gmail.com
```

my expected error1 response:

```
{
    "message": "teacher email address must be in proper format"
}
```

my actual error1 response:

```
{
    "message": "listOfStudentsCommonToAGivenListOfTeachers.teacherEmails[0].<list element>: teacher email address must be in proper format"
}
```

my endpoint2 on postman:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/commonstudents?teacher=&teacher=teacher2@gmail.com
```

my expected error2 response:

```
{
    "message": "teacher Email cannot be blank"
}
```

my actual error2 response:

```
{
    "message": "listOfStudentsCommonToAGivenListOfTeachers.teacherEmails[0].<list element>: teacher Email cannot be blank"
}
```

my endpoint3 on postman:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/commonstudents
```

my expected error3 response:

```
{
    "message": "Please input at least one email"
}
```

my actual error3 response:

```
{
    "message": "listOfStudentsCommonToAGivenListOfTeachers.teacherEmails: Please input at least one email"
}
```

The usual practice is you just put @Valid in the method parameter itself and you define the validation in a seperate class but this applies for objects while my case is a List which there is no class for me to work on. It works with the `@Validated` on class level only hence it triggers `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` unlike the usual cases where it triggers `MethodArgumentNotValidException`

The issue is it shows the whole family bloodline when I just wanted the error message defined by me. I tried to debug and saw this error message is always tied together with the method name ie not properly hidden. Is there a way to just get the error message defined? if no, is there another approach for this issue?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

violation.getPropertyPath().toString() + ": " you are constructing the error messages with property path thats why.

Change that line to this :

```java
List<String> errorMessages = e.getConstraintViolations().stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).collect(Collectors.toList());
```